# it works fine on desktop, but not on android. why?

Tags: android

saving socres to highscore.sav file, it works fine on desktop, but not on android. why?

```
String fileName = "highScores.sav";

file = new File(fileName);

public static void save(){

        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(gd);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }

    public static void load(){

        try{
            if(!saveFileExists()){
                init();
                return;
            }
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            gd = (GameData) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }
```

got error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /highScores.sav: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: were would you say your file is created when you do that?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please post a stack trace. It's hard to figure out what happens otherwise.

Comment: cant save file to android, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because you have not specified a directory to save into. Android has tight restrictions on where an app can write files.

You don't need any permissions to read or write a file to internal memory. But you do need to specify internal memory (called local memory in libgdx).

Libgdx already handles this directly for you so you don't need to differentiate between desktop and Android. [This explains exactly how to do it.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#writing-to-a-file) All you need is the string or bytes you want to write into the file, and the libgdx API's handle the rest.

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local(filename);
file.writeString(stringToWrite, false);
```

If you want to continue using your method of writing the file, you can get the path to the file like this:

```
String fileName = "highScores.sav";
file = new File(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath () + "/" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the permission to the android app to allow writing to the storage space?

Comment: Add this to your manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />. More information can be found here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html